# Python regex to correct number format

Tags: python, string

I have text files containing 1000's of numbers in the format 1 3434,00 or 12 4453,00
I need to turn them into US/UK local using python so that they are  13434.00 124453.00.

What regex expression or replace expression would I use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression:

```
x = text.replace(",", ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the phone numbers are read from the file and stored in the phone_number variable.
So, what you could do is replace the space with nothing and comma with dot.

```
phone_number = phone_number.replace(' ','')
phone_number = phone_number.replace(',','.')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your "numbers" are embedded in text, then you can try the following:

```py
import re

test = '''
I have text files containing 1000's of numbers in the format 1 3434,00 or 12 4453,00 I need to turn them into US/UK local using python so that they are 13434.00 124453.00.

What regex expression or replace expression would I use to do this?
'''

def to_number_string(m):
    s = m.group()
    print(repr(s))
    return s.replace(' ', '').replace(',', '.')

r = re.compile(r'\d+[ \d]*,\d*')
print(r.sub(to_number_string, test))
```